# Display Two Different Images in Two Different Image Controls using Image Provider in QT5

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I have a Project Which displys image clicked by IP Camera it is Displying image unsing image Provider class and in Image Control now what i want is to click 2 images and disply that two images in two Different IMAGE CONTROL i am new to qt and i have tried many ways but get no sucess my current code is as below

For Registering image Provider

```
 engine.addImageProvider(QLatin1String("capturedImage"), capturedImageProvider);
```

Image Provider is written like below
#include 
#include "imageProvider.h"

```
ImageProvider::ImageProvider(QObject *parent) : 
QQuickImageProvider(QQmlImageProviderBase::Image)
{

}

QImage ImageProvider::requestImage(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize& 
requestedSize)
{
    QImageReader reader("output.png");
    //QImageReader reader(id);
    QImage newImage = reader.read();
    return newImage;
}
```

in qml i have written like below

```
 onUpdateCapturedImage: {
        fmImage.source = "image://capturedImage?id=" + Math.random()
        
        fmImage2.source = "image://capturedImage?id=" + Math.random()
        
        btCapture.enabled = true
        pin.visible = false
        btCancel.visible = false
        btCapture.visible =true
        lbFileName.visible = false
        tmUpdateProgress.stop()
        if(status) {
            lbFileName.text = fileName;
        }
```

Here fmImage and fmImage2 is IMAGE CONTROLS CURRENTLY both controls display same image i want them to disply different images how can i do that please someone explain me with small example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to specify which image to display is in the ID field. Currently, you are passing `Math.random()` as an ID, and then ignoring it in your requestImage function. But if you change that so that the ID is meaningful, you can decide which image to return.

```
onUpdateCapturedImage: {
    fmImage.source = "image://capturedImage?id=" + firstId
    fmImage2.source = "image://capturedImage?id=" + secondId
}
```

```
QImage ImageProvider::requestImage(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize& 
requestedSize)
{
    QImageReader reader;

    if (id == firstId)
    {
        reader.setFileName("output1.png");
    }
    else if (id == secondId)
    {
        reader.setFileName("output2.png");
    }
    else
    {
        // Unknown image
    }

    QImage newImage = reader.read();
    return newImage;
}
```